# Create random values from sequence but with exact unique number of observations repeated randomly

Tags: r, dataframe, random, unique

I desire to create a random vector of 9776 integer from a specific sequence of numbers, in this case from 1 to 14610, but the unique number of observations has to be equal to 2444 and each observation has to be repeated randomly, i.e. NOT 2444 unique observations repeated each one 4 times.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: if we have got let's say 10 random observations with 4 unique values the repetition of the unique values could be 2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5, or 2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5...

Comment: yes...fine....this is what I want. repetition can be 1, 3, 5, 10, 24, or wathever times

Comment: please feel free to edit my question

Comment: Lets use your example fo4 2:5,  `sample(rep(sample(2:5), sample(length(2:5))))` here, the length is 10

Comment: Can you check the new update.  Here, you have to relax one of the conditions i.e. 9776 total elements otherwise, mathematically, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` to get the `length` about 9776 and then do the `sample`

```
df <- data.frame(x= sample(rep(seq_len(2444), length.out=9776)))
length(unique(df$x))
#[1] 2444
```

If we need to replace the `length.out` with `each` it can done as well

```
df1 <- data.frame(x= sample(rep(seq_len(2444), each = 4)))
length(unique(df1$x))
#[1] 2444
```

Or as @lmo mentioned

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(c(sample(2444), sample(2444, 9776-2444, replace=TRUE))))
```

Or

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(rep(sample(2444), length.out = 9776)))
length(unique(df$x))
#[1] 2444

head(df$x)
#[1]  858 1505 1631  105   79  268
tail(df$x)
#[1]   51 1545  100 1398 2261  682
```

#### Update

With the OP's updated question

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=sample(rep(head(sample(14610), 2444), each = 4)))
length(unique(df1$x))
#[1] 2444
```

#### Update2

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = sample(rep(head(sample(14610), 2444), 
                           sample(rep(1:4, length.out=2444))))) 
length(unique(df1$x))
#[1] 2444

table(table(df1$x))

#   1   2   3   4 
#  611 611 611 611
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I actually have 2444 unique values. but each observation has been repeated 4 times! this is not random I think.....

Comment: @aaaaa  Here the replication is not random, only the `sample` wrapping is

Comment: Oops. I misread it, they want to make sure all 2444 numbers are present at least once in the 9776 sampled elements.

Comment: @aaaaa  Please check the update as I also created a solution with double `sample`

Comment: yes, dont worry..I am just trying to apply them to my real data.

Comment: Here is another version: `sample(c(sample(2444), sample(2444, 9776-2444, replace=TRUE)))`. The second `sample` ensures that all integers are present and the third fills in the remaining 9776. The first `sample` shuffles these values around (permutes). I guess equivalently `sample(c(seq_len(2444), sample(2444, 9776-2444, replace=TRUE)))`.

Comment: @aaaaa  Updated the answer

Comment: each must be random and not fixed

Comment: @aaaaa  Each is random,  If you look at the first `sample(14610)`

Comment: @aaaaa  If you want one more layer of `sample`, then `df1 <- data.frame(x=sample(rep(sample(sample(14610), 2444), each = 4)));
 length(unique(df1$x))#[1] 2444`

Comment: table(df1$x) I dont want all values repeated 4 times but some repeated 3, 10, 12, 1, 25, etc....

Comment: @aaaaa  I think then your question is incomplete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143512/discussion-between-aaaaa-and-akrun).